# A font does not render in Word, Windows says it is installed

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, fonts

I have the Meta font family as .ttf and .otf files. On a Windows 7 laptop, I copied them into the Control Panel -> Fonts directory. But when I open a word document using a font of the Meta family, it gets rendered in another font (looks like Tahoma) and also prints in the other font.

Double-clicking the font files or copying them again into the fonts directory results in an error message telling me that the font is already installed. I know that the font files are OK, because I had them installed when the laptop still had Windows XP and I never had a problem then.

So, my question is, how do I install the font correctly so Word 2007 can use it?

Comment: Are other applications able to use the font?

Comment: @Nano8Blazex I set FBReader to MetaNormal and it displayed the current eBook in MetaNormal. I don't have another application capable of opening Word files to reopen the .doc file and see how it is displayed.

Comment: Silly suggestion but you have tried restarting MSWord right? :)

Comment: solved this by running word in safe mode (run that: winword /safe ), create  new doc, write and see if your font appear. It did for me, close the word-safe-mode, reopen your doc just by clicking on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your system up-to-date with the latest patches?  Some time ago Microsoft patched their OpenType/TrueType rendering engine because of a security issue, and that caused some fonts to not work anymore.  They [fixed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978909/) this later with a better fix that didn't disable those fonts.

Comment: Not sure that this was the reason, but it works now after the hundred things I did (including updating everything). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go in MS Word `Option`/ `Advanced` then in the `Show document content` section, uncheck `Use Draft Font in Draft and Outline Views`

[Source and printscreen](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T013207_Unwanted_Font_in_Draft_View.html)

---

*This could also work but it doesn't seem to be permanent:*

1. Close Word
2. Hold the Windows key down and press R.
3. In the Run box that opens type winword /safe (note there is a space between winword and /) and click on Ok.
4. press CTRL-N to open a new document.

If you are not able to open the Run box Click on Start > All Programs > Accessories > Run and type in the command winword /safe and click on Ok.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/adobe-fonts-do-not-render-correctly-in-ms-word/a6c7637d-4443-4a21-bfcf-dd7c8bf5f843)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and my Office version said it was the newest version. Following the suggestion of updating everything I uninstalled Office and installed it again to make sure I have the newest version and this solved the problem for me (Using the internal update tool it just told me that I'm up to date, but I was skeptical...).

Just wanted to mention it if the problem still occurs for somebody else.
I am using the Student Version of Office 365, I mention this as on the Microsoft Forum it also seemed everyone who had this issue was using the Student Version.