# Installed font is missing in Word

Tags: windows-7, fonts, microsoft-word-2010

I installed a new OTF font in Windows 7 and it is still listed as missing in Word 2010. Why?

[image]

This may be related [A font does not render in Word, Windows says it is installed](https://superuser.com/questions/179578/a-font-does-not-render-in-word-windows-says-it-is-installed), but there is no solution that works there.

Comment: Did you restart your computer?

Comment: Yes, I did restart. I have been using the computer for couple days already, restarted word, opened/closed multiple documents, nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rebuilding the Font Cache.

> The Windows operating system has a font cache file that is located
>   here:
>
> `C:\Windows\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT`
>
> Delete this file, and restart your system.

*[(Source)](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/49179-windows-7-64-bit-fonts-not-shown-4.html)*