# One specific OTF font is missing in Word only

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-word-365

One specific font installed on my computer doesn’t appear in the dropdown fonts list in Word. What could be the issue? How can I investigate further?

It’s a semibold OpenType font, all the other fonts in the same family work great. Semibold variants in other font families work just fine too. The missing font works perfectly in Adobe InDesign. It even works in Word on my Macbook (version 16.54, 2019).

I tried reinstalling the font, restarting Word, even restarting my computer.

Installed version is: Word 365 MSO build 2109. OS: Windows 10

I can’t upload the font file because its use is reserved. But again it works just fine in Adobe InDesign, and in Word on another computer, so it doesn’t seem to be an issue with the file.

Update: it seems like other people in the same company have the exact same issue with this font exactly, while using different versions of Word.

Comment: Before posting, I tried applying the solution to https://superuser.com/questions/455715/installed-font-is-missing-in-word. It didn’t work in my case (after all that question is almost 12 years old), and actually made things worse by extending the problem to two other variants of the same font family. The FNTCACHE.DAT file wasn’t recreated at startup, and putting it back in place (I had just renamed it) didn’t fix anything, including the two additional fonts missing now…

Comment: Any program will not see a new font until the program is closed and reopened. Also, There are different types of fonts. Word does not understand the old .fon type, but does understand the .ttf and even the open font standard. Also each font has a windows and mac version, but in case you go the mac on windows approach, no program can use that font.

Comment: Word dropped Type1 font support a number of years ago, is the missing font "Type 1?" (pfb; pfa file). FYI Adobe will be dropping type 1 between this year and 2023 IIRC

Comment: Anything more that you could tell us about this font? Like its file extension, and also the Details tab when right-clicking the font in *Control Panel > Fonts*.

Comment: It’s an OTF font. The only other info I can find is a version number of 001.000, and that it was made (I guess) by a software from Adobe Systems Incorporated. These characteristics are exactly the same as another font in the same family, which works fine in Word.

Comment: Update: it seems like other people in the same company have the exact same issue with this font exactly, while using different versions of Word.